# Cannot retrieve posted data from vue.js ajax call

Tags: codeigniter, vue.js

I'm giving a try to Vue.js, It's much simpler than Angular and then I stuck on this problem. I'm using CodeIgniter for the backend process. Basically I just want to send data using ajax call via Vue.js then I want to retrieve the data in mmy controller. But I can't retrive the data using `$this->input->post()`.

Here is my view. I'm using form on a modal.

```
<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="modalObat" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Tambah Obat</h4>
          </div>
          <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nama-obat" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama Obat</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namaObat" placeholder="nama obat" v-model="newObat.nama">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="harga" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Harga</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="harga" placeholder="harga" v-model="newObat.harga">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Stok" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stok</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="stok" placeholder="jumlah" v-model="newObat.stok">
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" id="simpen" class="btn btn-outline">Save Changes</button>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This is how I send the data on vue
[image]
Then here is my controller

```
public function tambahObat()
{
    $data = array(
            'nama'  => $this->input->post('nama'),
            'harga' => $this->input->post('harga'),
            'stok'  => $this->input->post('stok')
        );

    $data1 = $this->input->post('newObat');

    $query = $this->obat_m->save($data, null);

    if( $query == true )
    {
        $message = $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'berhasil menyimpan');
    }
    else
    {
        $message = $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'berhasil mengupdate');
    }

    redirect('obat');
}
```

I succeed to send the data as I check on the console

[image]

I think there is a problem with the controller but I dont know why. Could you help me, please??

Comment: Try `$post_data = file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: thank you @Yash. It worked well

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `this` from inside the post callback, where `this` refers to something other than your vue instance.  Try this format:

```
this.$http.post('url/to/post',{},function(){

    //because of "bind", 'this' is vue

}.bind(this));
```